# Phonegap adding multiple FileTransfer params of the same key, but different values

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, query-string

I am using phonegap to upload a file to a server and it is working well with a single exception...

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();

options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = file.name;

var params = new Object();

if($scope.SelectedNames.length >0){
params.shareWith = SelectedNames[0].id;
//params.shareWith = [$scope.SelectNames[0].id,$scope.SelectNames[1].id]; 
}

options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();          
ft.upload(file.toURL(), "https://mysupersecret.url.com", win, fail, options, true);
//the rest of it
```

The problem is sometimes I have multiple "SelectedNames" which need to be added to the shareWith parameter.  If I try setting .shareWith to an array, it doesn't work.  I have tried creating the POST query string myself, but that doesnt work either.  Obviously just calling an additional `params.shareWith='xyz'` just overwrites the first value.

Thoughts?

I want it to submit it with a query string of :

?shareWith=value1&shareWith=value2&shareWith=value3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current implementation of FileTransfer in PhoneGap makes this tricky, but it is possible. The problem is the format of [multipart/form-data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) in the post. For the server to correctly interpret a parameter as multi-valued, the raw request payload needs to have a series of Content-Disposition lines with the same name , like this:

```
--AaB03x
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="shareWith[]"

   Joe

--AaB03x
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="shareWith[]"

   Jim

--AaB03x
   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="shareWith[]"

   Jane
```

The array notation in the name indicates that the parameter is multi-valued, and the server will interpret this parameter as an array of values, the way you want.

Unfortunately, this is the Objective-C code in the Cordova libs that appends the data to the request payload:

```
    NSDictionary* options = [arguments objectAtIndex:5 withDefault:nil];
    ...
    for (NSString* key in options) {
            ...
            [postBodyBeforeFile appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:
                @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] 
                dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

All it does is iterate through your params object (it expects a JS object like `{ param1: 'one', param2: 'two' }`) and pass each param object key to the key in this method call. It's not smart enough to check to see if the value is an array and if so, append multiple Content-Disposition lines - as you can see from the for statement, it assumes that each key is a string only. And because the options dictionary can't have multiple values with the same key, the form can't be created with Content-Disposition lines with the same name, the way you'd need to to submit multi-valued parameters.

However, you should be able to achieve what you want in a less-than-elegant way by building the form names yourself, like this:

```
params = {}
params['shareWith[0]'] = 'Joe';
params['shareWith[1]'] = 'Jim';
params['shareWith[2]'] = 'Jane';
```

The result on the server may be a little different from the above, but this should get you most of the way there. Hopefully this will be addressed in the future and you'll be able to use multi-valued parameters a little more rationally with FileTransfer.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, people like you inspire me to move my programming to the next level.

Comment: Had a facepalm moment this morning when I realized that this is possible after all, if a little ugly. I left the implementation stuff because I think it's kinda interesting, though.

Comment: this doesn't work, I am unsure why it might since shareWith[0] and shareWith[1] are different keys ?

Comment: Different keys, yes, but the array notation indicates to the server that they belong to the same multi-valued array. I haven't tried this myself with Phonegap, but manually building a form with two inputs of name "multi[0]" and "multi[1]" and submitting that to a Rails server works for me. When you submit shareWith[0] and shareWith[1] via Phonegap, what do you get on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a queue to upload from the SelectedNames array? After one is complete, shift it from the array and see if there are any left. Demonstration:

```
// Start the queue
if(SelectedNames.length >0)
{
    runQueue();
}

function runQueue()
{
    if(SelectedNames.length > 0)
    {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();

        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = file.name;

        var params = new Object();
        params.shareWith = SelectedNames[0].id;
        options.params = params;

        SelectedNames.shift();

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(file.toURL(), "https://mysupersecret.url.com", runQueue, fail, options, true);

    }
    else
    {
        // ALL DONE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
params.shareWith0 = value1;
params.shareWith1 = value2;
params.shareWith2 = value3;
//...
params.shareWithCount = xy.Length;
```

Or you could use a delimiter that never appears in your values.

```
params.shareWith = [value1, value2, value3].join("~");
```

Another, even less clean, option would be to use jQuerys [param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

```
$.param({shareWith: [value1, value2, value3]})
```